# Reading in a positive number in C

Tags: c, validation

I'm trying to find the most efficient way to read in a positive number in C. I can't use just scanf("%u", &var) because scanf takes the two's complement of negative numbers thereby screwing up the number. I also don't really want to read characters in manually into a buffer, because that requires me to know before-hand the maximum number of digits, which really I only want to be limited by UINT_MAX.

Any ideas, things I've most probably overlooked?

Comment: Can you give an example of the screw up?

Comment: Using scanf("%u", &var) and entering -1, var will be set to the two's complement value, but there's no way to distinguish between someone entering a number that large and someone entering -1.

Comment: The maximum number of decimal digits is not so hard to "guess": 10 for 32-bit values; 20 for 64-bits; 39 for 128-bits; 78 for 256-bits; ... just use a `static char buf[MAX_DECIMAL_DIGITS_64BIT + 1]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe somtehing like this:

```
char sign = getchar();
if ('-' == sign) {
    //error
} else {
    ungetchar(sign);
    scanf("%u", &var) 
}
```

Comment: i) It will fail with `" -1"` ii) I only have a `ungetc(sign, stdin)` function available

Comment: It's a bit of a hack in my opinion, but seems to work. I ended up doing: `char ch; while ((ch = getc(stdin)) == ' ' || ch == '\f' || ch == '\t' || ch == '\v' || ch == '\n' || ch == '\r'); if (ch != '-'){ungetc(ch, stdin);scanf("%u", &var);}` instead to ensure whitespace doesn't cause problems

Comment: @Adam: why not `while (isspace(ch = fgetc(stdin)));`? This deals with the same characters as in your code plus any other stuff available on "strange" locales -- and it's easier on the eyes.

Comment: wat abt if hexadecimal or octal input? Its better to use strtoul() functionality provided by standard library in else part of the above code. have a look at following url on how to do tat..mind it for strtol [link](http://jk-technology.com/c/code/strtol.html)

Answer (score 0):

What about reading a `signed int` from the user, and if it is negative show an error to the user:

```
int var;
scanf("%d", &var);

if (var < 0) {
    printf("Error: %d is negative", var);
}
else {
    /* use the positive number */
    unsigned int positive = var;
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: The "problem" with this solution is that you lose half the range of unsigned integers.

Comment: That is true, but there is always the possibility that the user enters an invalid (in this case negative) number. This case has to be spotted and handled correctly. To achieve this, we have to take the drawback of losing half of the range of numbers. One possibility is to parse the input as a `long integer`, which has a wider range on some systems.